# CIImage extent crash

Tags: ios, xcode, core-image, cgimage, ciimage

I got this method that grabs the camera buffer image to do some image processing every few seconds.

Below method runs fine on all my testing, yet this is present in crash reports with a significant amount of crashes.

```
final func cameraBufferProcessing () {

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).sync { [unowned self] in
            if let bufferImage = self.cameraBufferImage?.oriented(.downMirrored) {
                let heightPropotion : CGFloat = bufferImage.extent.height * 0.5 //Crashes on this line
                if let cgImg = self.context.createCGImage(bufferImage.clampedToExtent(), from: CGRect(x: 0, y: heightPropotion, width: bufferImage.extent.width, height: heightPropotion))
                {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                        // use with cgImg to do image processing
                    }

                }
            } else {
                // do something else 
            }
        }
    }
```

Crash reports point to the third line above:

```
let heightPropotion : CGFloat = bufferImage.extent.height * 0.5
```

Crash seems to be related to extent.

What could be the cause here?

Comment: "Crash seems to be related to extent." How do you know? _Show_ us the entire crash log, please. Is it a threading error? If so, why are you getting on a background thread here? Surely the "slow" method is only `self.context.createCGImage`, so that would be the only line that needs to be wrapped in a background queue, yes? The notion that you are going to access `self.cameraBufferImage` on a background queue is quite scary, if you ask me. Have you tried running this code with the Thread Sanitizer turned on?

Comment: Well noted!  I will move the background thread down to create CGImage method.  Is it possible extent to be infinite or zero with above code?

Comment: Also `DispatchQueue.sync` will block the call anyways. This is probably not your intention...

Comment: @FrankSchlegel nice point, I didn't even notice that, I was so concerned with the actual queues.

Comment: Is there a chance extent might come out nil or something other than a number?